# For Loop and Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
var brackets = [];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    brackets.push(15 += 5)
}
```

I want to use this code to add a new element to the array each time, but the new elements have to be added in increments of 5, starting from 15. It will go 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40.

Comment: What do you expect `15 += 5` to do?

Comment: I've tried this: 
var brackets = [15];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    brackets.push(brackets[0] += 5)
}
But it gives this output: [ 40, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 ]

Comment: I just want to start from 15 and add 5 each time for every new element

Comment: Then do just that: `for (var i = 15; i <= 40; i += 5) { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

```
var brackets = [];
for(i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    brackets.push(15+5*i))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var brackets = [];
for(var i = 15; i < 45; i+=5){
    brackets.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var brackets = [];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    brackets.push(15 += 5)
}
```

First of all, when  you put "15 += 5" means nothing, because 15 is a number not a variable.. unless you put a variable "a" like this:

```
var brackets = [15];
var a=15;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    brackets.push(a += 5)
}
```

and

```
var brackets = [15];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){ brackets.push(brackets[0] += 5) }
```

> But it gives this output: [ 40, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40 ]

well.. "brackets[0]" is a variable... when you do "brackets[0] += 5" it will do 15+5 and store the result (20) on brackets[0], after that it does "brackets.push(20)" in which brackets has now [20,20]..
the second time it will be [25,20,25], after that [30,20,25,30] and so on until you get [40,20,25,30,35,40]..
A solution for this one would be:

```
var brackets = [15];
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){ brackets.push(brackets[i] + 5) }
```